# Copy/paste not works in VmWare machine with raspbian

Tags: raspbian, virtualization, raspberry-pi-desktop

I have installed [Raspberry Pi Desktop](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/) to my `VmWare` virtual machine hosted by `windows 10`.

I have also installed vmtools:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
```

But I still cant copy/paste and drag and drop files between machines while these features are enabled:

[image]

How to fix that?

Comment: This is a question about VmWare